# passing parameter with hive -e option

Tags: hive

How can I pass parameter/variable with `hive -e` option.

I want to run the following command: `hive -e 'msck repair table $dbname.table1'` and it is failing as it is unable to read the variable.

What is the way around. I am writing it in a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [variable substitution](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution).

For Hive version **>= 0.8.0**:

```
$ hive --hivevar dbname=<your_value> -e 'msck repair table ${hivevar:dbname}.table1'
```

For Hive version **< 0.8.0**:

```
$ hive --hiveconf dbname=<your_value> -e 'msck repair table ${hiveconf:dbname}.table1'
```

Comment: I believe it should be one hyphen like "hive -hiveconf dbnm=$db_dbname -e ' set dbnm; msck repair table ${hiveconf:dbnm}.table1'". This one worked for me.

Comment: @KoushikChandra interesting, looks like both single and double hyphen work. However, I would prefer to use double hyphen since it's the way it appears in both link I provided and when calling `hive --help`